# Java most efficent way to merge several sets/lists

Tags: java, algorithm, merge

My basic problem is that I have 4 different datasources(DS1, DS2, DS3,DS4) that I currently store in 4 different lists. Every list is filled with InformationObjects and these objects have four fields that are identifiers if they exist, but all of them does not have to exist. And then there is about 20 fields containing random information about the object.

What I then need to do is to merge these lists into a new one and if two objects from different datasources have the same of any of the identifiers they should be considered as the same object and their fields should be merged.

Example:

```
Object1
  idField1: "123"
  idField3: "437"
  infoField1: "info1"
  infoField2: "info2"

Object2
  idField1: "123"
  idField2: "gfd"
  idField4: "9987"
  infoField3: "info3"
  infoField4: "info4"

Object3
  idField2: "gfd"
  infoField5: "info5"

Merged
  idField1: "123"
  idField2: "gfd"
  idField3: "437"
  idField4: "9987"
  infoField1: "info1"
  infoField2: "info2"
  infoField3: "info3"
  infoField4: "info4"
  infoField5: "info5"
```

This merge will be done a lot so I need to find the fastest way to do it. So my question is how you can do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: Did you want javascript or java?

Comment: Is preserving ordering important, or do you just need them combined without any duplicates?

Comment: @Kayaman It is in java, I just used json to present the objects easier :).

Comment: @CBHacking Order is not important, the important thing is that I can combine objects that have the same of any identifier.

Comment: So your objects are String,String pairs? Using JSON here doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: @Kayaman I apologize for any confusion. It was just a way to show how the objects were structured. I updated my original post to not include json. They are just objects of the InformationObject class.

Comment: You can create a concatenated Iterable view in O(1) using one of Guava's [Iterables.concat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) methods, but what are you requesting is a bit different I think. You want to create a new InformationObject based on the id fields which contains the information from both the objects?

Comment: @Narmer I'm not sure how that would help? As I understand that method it will only give me a single iterator for all lists? It wont merge my fields.

Comment: @unzoomed Yes, what you request is different. I think you should implement a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)  for the objects to test if they have at least one id in common and then create a new InformationObject with a merging factory (something like `InformationObject merge(InformationObject a, InformationObject b);`) and add it to a new list.

Comment: You could use simple and fast merge algorithm (complexity O(1) for space and O(n) for time) if the lists coming from each datasource are ordered by ID. Are they ordered?

Comment: @kan I'm afraid that they are not ordered. And would this really work when I have 4 different ID parameters and none of the datasources has all 4?

Comment: @unzoomed AFAIU you want to merge two items if they share a common identifier and such items are in four lists, not simply merge four lists. Maybe you should change the title accordingly.

Comment: If they are not ordered, then you should understand how much memory do you have. Could you load all data into in-memory hash-maps?

Comment: @kan Memory is not an issue, so yes I would be able to load all items into memory.

Comment: So, then it is trivial - create HashMap ID->Object for each datasource and then just iterate over each map and look for matched IDs from other maps. Or even simpler to do - create additional HashSet for all IDs. Then iterate over the set and look into each HashMap for data. Is it enough? Or you need a code example?

Comment: @kan but I do not understand how I would do that when I can have several ID's on a single object from a single datasource. Like in Object1 above I have ifField1 and idField3 on a single object. Should I use two hashmaps with duplicate data?

Comment: I've published a code snipped, have a look. The method `mergeObjects` takes list of all objects having same id from all datasources. It is up to your business requirements how exactly to merge data into single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<InformationObject> doMerge()
{
  Map<String, List<InformationObject>> map = new HashMap<>();
  addData(map, ds1);
  addData(map, ds2);
  addData(map, ds3);
  addData(map, ds4);

  List<InformationObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for(List<InformationObject> ios: map.values())
  {
    InformationObject io = mergeObjects(ios);
    result.add(io);
  }
  return result;
}

private void addData(Map<String, List<InformationObject>> map, Datasource ds)
{
   for(InformationObject io : ds...)
   {
     String id = io.getId();
     List<InformationObject> list = map.get(id);
     if(list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(io);
   }
}
```

Comment: I can absolutely see how this can work if I have a single id field, but I fail to see it when I have several. I updated my original post to more clearly show how the data may look. Sorry if I was unclear from the start. And from what I can see if I use your example snippet object 3 wont be put in the same list as object 1 and 2 due to that object 3 doesn't have idfield1?

Comment: @unzoomed If it doesn't have id, how do you know with which one it should be merged? Or do you mean that it may have ID in different fields? Just modify example to merge lists from datasources merging different criteria.

Comment: @unzoomed In other words. E.g. if `DS1` and `DS2` should be merged by `idField1`, merge them. Then you will have a merged list `DS1+DS2`. Then use the same algorithm to merge `DS1+DS2` and `DS3` using `idField2` and so on.

Comment: thank you for all your responses and your effort! I will try out this solution, it seems like a reasonable one. However I'm afraid I could have the problem that DS1 uses idField1 on some objects and idField2 on some, and this could cause problems.

Comment: @unzoomed Then you could have several hashmaps - one per merge field. If an object is matched by any of id field, then merge objects. Is it clear how? If you need, I could write a code to clarify.